# How could i subtract two different values from the same column in different rows?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make an update statement in Mysql where I need to subtract two different values from two columns of two rows.

```
UPDATE `posts` 
SET `calc` = calc - 1 
WHERE `id` IN (1, 2);
```

This way it works, but only subtract the value by one, I need to subtract two different values, something like that:

```
UPDATE `posts` 
SET `calc` = calc - (1, 2) 
WHERE `id` in (1,2);
```

- When `id = 1`, subtract 1 from `calc`
- When `id = 2`, subtract 2 from `calc`

Thanks.

Comment: That wouldn't do what is being asked @easleyfixed :)

Comment: Is this an exercise or a real live requirement. Because you could do it but it would be simpler just to run 2 seperate queries

Comment: @easleyfixed Then write the OP an answer

Comment: Thx, guys. Alredy solved.

Answer (score 0):

Is it an example or a real case? you can solve this case with a CASE statement:

You can use a CASE statement to achieve this:

```
UPDATE `posts` SET `calc` = 
    CASE 
        WHEN `id` = 1 THEN `calc` - 1
        WHEN `id` = 2 THEN `calc` - 2
    END
WHERE `id` in (1, 2);
```